# rb.velocity at update works strange (beginner question)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to ask a question for better understanding of unity. I have made dash for platfromer game, here is the code for dash and could you please explain why this code doesn't work

```
void Update 
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
    {
        isDashing = true;
        currentDashTimer = dashTimer;
        rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
    }

    if (isDashing) {
        Dash();
    }
}

public void Dash() 
{
    if (currentDashTimer <= 0)
    {
        isDashing = false;
    }
    else if (facingRight)
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector2.right * dashForce;
    } 
    else if (!facingRight)
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector2.left * dashForce;
    }

    currentDashTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
}
```

But this works:

```
void Update 
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
    {
        isDashing = true;
        currentDashTimer = dashTimer;
        rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
    }
}

public void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (isDashing)
    {
        Dash();
    }
} 

public void Dash() 
{
    if (currentDashTimer <= 0)
    {
        isDashing = false;
    }
    else if (facingRight)
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector2.right * dashForce;
    } 
    else if (!facingRight)
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector2.left * dashForce;
    }

    currentDashTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
}
```

So if I call `Dash()` at `Update()` it will not actually work, SO if I change dashForce it will not affect anything even if I add `Time.fixedDeltaTime`, but in second example where `Dash()` is called at FixedUpdate() everything works fine.

Why?

I just have this question because, I have a `Move()` function that is similar to `Dash()` but move works properly at `Update()` and `FixedUpdate()`

Comment: Fixed update called every 0.02 second . so if you have saying 25 fps . you will end up having 50 fixed update calls. So in update function you are setting velocity to zero when E  key is pressed so every frame update you are setting zero velocity. In case of fixed update you will have twice call and script have time to move object until it's velocity zeroes

Comment: Shorty fixedupdate is called more often than update in your case that's why it is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem I defined in comment

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
{
    isDashing = true;
    currentDashTimer = dashTimer;
}
else
{
    rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
}
```